# Let $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ an analytic function defined in a region U of $\mathbb{C}$, such that $|f^2(z)-1|<1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ an analytic function defined in a region U of $\mathbb{C}$, such that $|f^2(z)-1|<1$ for all $z\in U$. Show that $Ref(z)<0$ or $Ref(z)>0$ in all U.

$Re f(z)$ can't be equal to 0, because, if $Re f(z)=0$, where $f=u+iv$ (because f is analytic), then $|f^2(z)-1|=|f(z)-1||f(z)+1|=|iv-1||iv+1|=v^2+1<1$ but $v^2\geq0$.

Comment: Are you missing a $<1$ qualifier..?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry.

Comment: Since $\operatorname{Re}f : U \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, it satisfies the intermediate value theorem as long as $U$ is connected, so...

Answer (score 1):

Fix $z\in U$,  and apply Rouche's Theorem to the analytic function $f^2$ on a disk $z\in D$ such that $\overline D\subseteq U$. Since $z$ is arbitrary in $U$, it follows that $f^2$ has no zero in $U$ and so neither does $f$. To finish, toward a contradiction, assume the claim is false and note that Re$ f(U)$ is connected (because $U$ is a region and Re$f$ is continuous).